# Looking for a simple web server on windows which is also case sensitive?

Tags: windows, web-server

I understand IIS cannot be case sensitive because the underlying filesystem is not case sensitive. I am deploying my web site in AWS Cloudfront which is case sensitive but my programmers are on windows.

Can someone suggest a good simple web server on windows which is also case sensitive?